# Перемещение прямоугольника с изменением положения его вершин

Tags: java, javafx, canvas

Добрый день! Не могу решить данную задачу, буду очень признателен. Необходимо обеспечить метаморфозу многоугольника из начальной формы(прямоугольник) в  заданную конечную форму(пятиугольник). Пробовал сделать таким образом, как на с++, но нет понятия, как это сделать.

```
public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{

    final int n = 100;
    final int m = 5;
    double x;
    double y;
    double[] Xmas = {10, 10, 100, 100, 100};
    double[] Ymas = {10, 100, 100, 50, 10};
    double[] EndXmas = {225, 275, 300, 250, 200};
    double[] EndYmas = {300, 300, 250, 200, 250};
    double[] KoefXmas = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    double[] KoefYmas = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        KoefXmas[i] = (EndXmas[i] - Xmas[i]) / n;
        KoefYmas[i] = (EndYmas[i] - Ymas[i]) / n;
    }
    final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(500,500);
    final GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
    gc.setFill(Color.AQUA);
    gc.fill();
            canvas.MoveTo(Xmas[0],Ymas[0]);
    for (int j = 0; j <= n; j++)
    {
        gc.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        if (j > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
            {
                Xmas[i] += KoefXmas[i];
                Ymas[i] += KoefYmas[i];
            }
            Canvas.MoveTo(Xmas[0],Ymas[0]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            Canvas.LineTo(Xmas[i],Ymas[i]);
        }
        Canvas.LineTo(Xmas[0],Ymas[0]);

        Sleep(10);


    Group root = new Group();

        root.getChildren().add(canvas);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();


}}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

Буду признателен любой помощи: хоть-то это будет книга или дельный совет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main.java

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        final Group pane = new Group();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 500 ,500));
        stage.show();

        stage.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, event -> {
            new Thread(new RenderingTask(pane)).start();
        });

    }
}
```

RenderingTask.java

```
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;

public class RenderingTask extends Task {

    private int n = 100;
    private int m = 5;

    private double[] EndXmas = {225, 275, 300, 250, 200};
    private double[] EndYmas = {300, 300, 250, 200, 250};

    private DoubleProperty [] Xmas = {
            new SimpleDoubleProperty(10)
            , new SimpleDoubleProperty(10)
            , new SimpleDoubleProperty(100)
            , new SimpleDoubleProperty(100)
            , new SimpleDoubleProperty(100)
    };

    private DoubleProperty [] Ymas = {
            new SimpleDoubleProperty(10)
            , new SimpleDoubleProperty(100)
            , new SimpleDoubleProperty(100)
            , new SimpleDoubleProperty(50)
            , new SimpleDoubleProperty(10)
    };

    private final Group pane;

    public RenderingTask(Group pane) {
        this.pane = pane;
    }

    protected Object call() throws Exception {

        double[] KoefXmas = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        double[] KoefYmas = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

        Line [] lines = new Line[m];

        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            KoefXmas[i] = (EndXmas[i] - Xmas[i].doubleValue()) / n;
            KoefYmas[i] = (EndYmas[i] - Ymas[i].doubleValue()) / n;

            lines[i] = new Line();

            lines[i].startXProperty().bind(Xmas[i]);
            lines[i].startYProperty().bind(Ymas[i]);

            if ( i == m - 1 ) {
                lines[i].endXProperty().bind(Xmas[0]);
                lines[i].endYProperty().bind(Ymas[0]);
            } else {
                lines[i].endXProperty().bind(Xmas[i + 1]);
                lines[i].endYProperty().bind(Ymas[i + 1]);
            }

        }

        Platform.runLater(() -> pane.getChildren().addAll(lines));

        for (int j = 0; j <= n; j++) {
            if (j > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                    Xmas[i].set(Xmas[i].doubleValue() + KoefXmas[i]);
                    Ymas[i].set(Ymas[i].doubleValue() + KoefYmas[i]);
                }
            }

            Thread.sleep(50);
        }

        Platform.runLater(() -> pane.getChildren().removeAll(lines));

        return null;
    }

}
```

Тест: запустить -> клик мыши (можно и несколько раз кликать)